# What should one say if saved from danger?

Tags: blessing, danger

For example, if one had a stone smash car glass while driving in a dangerous place, but was not hit himself?

Answer (score 1):

There is a blessing just for that, called `בירכת הגומל`=`Birkat Ha-Gomel`
Its a bit hard to translate to English, but something like `the blessing of the one who is in charge of Rewarding for good and evil`.

It thanks god, who is in charge of rewarding for good and bad, who is rewarding me for the good.

I encountered some changes for the actual text for different Jewish streams, but all say the same.

You can read [Here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Birkat_HaGomel)